# If $X$ is a subset of $\omega_{\alpha}$ such that $|X| < \aleph_{\alpha}$, then $|\omega_{\alpha} - X| = \aleph_{\alpha}$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

If $\alpha=0$, then $\omega_0=\mathbb{N}$ and $\aleph_0=$ countable. So $|\omega_{\alpha} - X| = \aleph_{\alpha}$ becomes $|\mathbb{N}-X|=|\mathbb{N}|$ which is true (the function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}-X$ by $f(n)=n+|X|$ is a bijection).

But when it is changed to $\alpha$, I have no idea how to proceed. I also have tried to use transfinite induction on $\alpha$ but I am getting nowhere.

Comment: If $|\omega_\alpha - X|<\omega_\alpha$, then $|X \cup \omega_\alpha - X| = max\{|X|,|\omega_\alpha - X|\}<\omega_\alpha$ which is impossible.

Comment: Since $\aleph_\alpha\times\aleph_\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$, we can use $\omega_\alpha\times\omega_\alpha$ instead of $\omega_\alpha$. It is easy to prove that there is an injection between $\omega_\alpha$ and $\omega_\alpha\times \omega_\alpha-X$ where $X$ is a subset of $\omega_\alpha\times \omega_\alpha$.

Comment: May I know why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to show that $|X \cup Y| = \text{max}(|X|, |Y|)$ when at least one of $X, Y$ is infinite.

Comment: Is this the same as $\aleph_{\alpha} +\aleph_{\beta} = \aleph_{\beta}$ for $\alpha \leq \beta$?